# What is the point of using LNA if the SDR can increase the gain itself

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, lna, snr

Usually there is a LNA next to antenna, while SDR devices also have gain setting so we can increase the gain.
As i know LNAs are amplifying all signals with same gain (Am I right?)
So i wonder what is the point of LNA here?
if the SDR device can amplify the signal using gain settings why should we use a LNAs?

Comment: There are [two](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/18479/how-much-db-gain-do-you-need-from-an-lna-in-front-of-an-antenna-for-great-low-si) [questions](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/9832/how-can-i-calculate-the-effects-of-an-lna-antenna-gain-etc-on-noise-performan) with good answers on this subject, the second one gives a detailed rundown of why LNAs help - do these answer your question?

Comment: @tomnexus: yes thanks, the second link made every thing clear.

Comment: awesome! then let's mark this as answered by that for future readers!